# hiveserver2 is shutting down frequently in hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive, thrift, beeline

Facing this issue from quite sometime now and not able to track the reason why is it happening.
Whenever we start hiveserver2 using command ->

```
./hiveserver2 &
```

It starts and stays up for sometime but then shuts down. In hive logs it does show the following error while hiveserver is up and running.

```
2018-03-12 04:44:57,029 ERROR [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-33]: server.TThreadPoolServer (TThreadPoolServer.java:run(296)) - Erro
r occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransportException: No data or no sasl data in the stream
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:268)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransportException: No data or no sasl data in the stream
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:328)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
        ... 4 more
2018-03-12 04:45:55,361 INFO  [main]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(951)) -
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/usr/local/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
```

But I'm not really sure that the shutting down of hiveserver is due to above error as it keeps on running for hours before shutting down.

Following are the hive logs that comes when hiveserver shuts down

```
2018-03-12 04:46:25,285 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(951)) - Stage-Stage-1: Map: 4  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU
: 18.09 sec   HDFS Read: 763046 HDFS Write: 2217 SUCCESS
2018-03-12 04:46:25,286 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(951)) - Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 18 seconds 90 mse
c
2018-03-12 04:46:25,286 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printInfo(951)) - OK
2018-03-12 04:46:25,286 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apach
e.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2018-03-12 04:46:25,295 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=152082998
5286 end=1520829985295 duration=9 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2018-03-12 04:46:25,295 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - </PERFLOG method=Driver.run start=15208299614
77 end=1520829985295 duration=23818 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2018-03-12 04:46:25,304 INFO  [main]: CliDriver (SessionState.java:printInfo(951)) - Time taken: 23.818 seconds
2018-03-12 04:46:25,304 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogBegin(121)) - <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apach
e.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2018-03-12 04:46:25,305 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) - </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=152082998
5304 end=1520829985305 duration=1 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
2018-03-12 04:46:36,351 INFO  [Thread-9]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveServer2.java:stop(305)) - Shutting down HiveServer2
2018-03-12 04:46:36,351 INFO  [Thread-9]: thrift.ThriftCLIService (ThriftCLIService.java:stop(201)) - Thrift server has stopped
2018-03-12 04:46:36,351 INFO  [Thread-9]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:stop(125)) - Service:ThriftBinaryCLIService is
 stopped.
2018-03-12 04:46:36,351 INFO  [Thread-9]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:stop(125)) - Service:OperationManager is stopp
ed.
2018-03-12 04:46:36,351 INFO  [Thread-9]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:stop(125)) - Service:SessionManager is stopped
.
2018-03-12 04:46:36,351 INFO  [Thread-3]: server.HiveServer2 (HiveStringUtils.java:run(709)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down HiveServer2 at SERVER-HOSTNAME/192.168.***.**
************************************************************/
2018-03-12 04:46:46,352 WARN  [Thread-9]: service.CompositeService (SessionManager.java:cleanupLoggingRootDir(213)) - Failed to cleanu
p root dir of HS2 logging: /usr/local/hive/log
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /usr/local/hive/log
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2275)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.cleanupLoggingRootDir(SessionManager.java:211)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.stop(SessionManager.java:205)
        at org.apache.hive.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:102)
        at org.apache.hive.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:92)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.stop(CLIService.java:165)
        at org.apache.hive.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:102)
        at org.apache.hive.service.CompositeService.stop(CompositeService.java:92)
        at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.stop(HiveServer2.java:307)
        at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2$1.run(HiveServer2.java:107)
2018-03-12 04:46:46,353 INFO  [Thread-9]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:stop(125)) - Service:CLIService is stopped.
2018-03-12 04:46:46,353 INFO  [Thread-9]: service.AbstractService (AbstractService.java:stop(125)) - Service:HiveServer2 is stopped.
2018-03-12 04:51:07,336 INFO  [main]: SessionState (SessionState.java:printInfo(951)) -
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/usr/local/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
```

If the issue is actually because of...

```
ERROR [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-33]: server.TThreadPoolServer (TThreadPoolServer.java:run(296)) - Erro
    r occurred during processing of message.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransportException: No data or no sasl data in the stream
```

...then here are my hive-site.xml settings which are related to it as mentioned in many other related posts.

```
<name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
<value>PAM</value>

<name>hive.server2.authentication.pam.services</name>
<value>sshd,sudo</value>

<name>hive.server2.thrift.sasl.qop</name>
<value>auth</value>

<name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
<value>false</value>
```

## EDITS

Tried starting hiveserver after changing **hive.server2.authentication** from **PAM** to **NONE** 
But Again hiveserver started with the following error

```
ERROR [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-31]: server.TThreadPoolServer (TThreadPoolServer.java:run(296)) - Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransportException: No data or no sasl data in the stream
```

also when trying to connect to beeline it throws connection exception as expected,

```
bin$ ./beeline
Beeline version 1.2.2 by Apache Hive
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://192.168.XXX.XX:XXX7 myuser myp@sw0rd
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://192.168.XXX.XX:XXX7
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://192.168.203.XXX.XX:XXX7: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) (state=08S01,code=0)
0: jdbc:hive2://192.168.XXX.XX:XXX7 (closed)>
0: jdbc:hive2://192.168.XXX.XX:XXX7 (closed)>
```

while ps -ef | grep hive shows that hiveserver is up

```
ps -ef | grep hive
hduser   30902 30165  1 05:39 pts/1    00:00:15 /data/apps/jdk/bin/java -Xmx4000m -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/usr/local/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=hduser -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar /usr/local/hive/lib/hive-service-1.2.2.jar org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2
```

Comment: Is the cluster kerberized?

Comment: @DeSanta - No, it's not kerberized.

Answer (score 0):

[HiveServer2 documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2#SettingUpHiveServer2-PluggableAuthenticationModules(PAM)) mentions that when using `PAM` authentication mode, if the user's password has expired, it will cause the server to go down. Please check if that's the case and you can also try setting `hive.server2.authentication` to `NONE` and check if that lets you connect to the server.

Comment: I've edited the question and added few more details as per your suggestions, please check

Comment: It all looks messed up here, ps -ef shows hiveserver2 is running but the logs shows - SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down HiveServer2

Comment: I've tried running it after changing PAM to NOSASL, hiveserver2 started without throwing any error this time and didn't shutdown, but still not able to connect from beeline. throwing same error as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

a time out on a connection may be just because it's not listening at all on the port, or not authorized to be connected.
`netstat -na` to check the port listening
`/etc/security/access.conf` 
or `iptable -L`

?